# Activate Gravity at Frame X

Tags: objects, physics, rigid-body-simulation

So I'm looking to have some text come crashing down. I have a cell fracture enabled and gravity starting disabled however, as I'm very new to blender, I don't have any clue on how to make the gravity only start to effect it at say frame 40. Would love any help!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by keyframing the Gravity checkbox in ***Properties>>Scene>>Gravity***.

1.) Select frame 40 and keyframe the **un**checked checkbox by pressing <kbd>i</kbd> or by right clicking and selecting "Insert Keyframe".

2.) Go to frame 41 and keyframe the **checked** checkbox by pressing <kbd>i</kbd>

[image]